# Panda create column

Tags: python, calculated-columns

Is there a way to create a column titled counter whereby if there is rainfall, the value in counter column will appear as 1, otherwise it will appear as 0?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `df['counter'] = df['Rainfall(mm)'].astype(bool)`. If you really want 0s and 1s, try `df['counter'] = df['Rainfall(mm)'].astype(bool).astype(int)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a gd alternative as well !

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['counter'] = (df['rainfall'] > 0).astype(int)
```

This way you generate a new column of booleans with `True` values for the rows with a rainfall value greater than 0, and transforming this column to integer values generates a column of zeros and ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Day': ['1/1/2021', '2/1/2021', '3/1/2021', '4/1/2021', ], 'Rainfall': [110, 120, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Counter']=df['Rainfall']>0
```

df content is:

```
        Day  Rainfall  Counter
0  1/1/2021       110     True
1  2/1/2021       120     True
2  3/1/2021         0    False
3  4/1/2021         0    False
```

Comment: Thanks this is a gd alternative as well !